# Convert Cell Values of DataTable to Percentages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a dynamically generated `DataTable` with bunch of different values:

```
Column1 | Column2  | Column3
----------------------------
230     | 265      | 272    
270     | 235      | 235    
250     | 235      | 254    
250     | 225      | 259
```

I want to show data of each cell this way:

- Each cell value in a column should be represented as percentage value of the column total.

For example instead of 230 in first cell of `Column1` in above table, I want to show `23.00%`. And it should calculate this way:

```
First Cell of Column 1: 23.00% = (230 / (230 + 270 + 250 + 250)) * 100
```

For example, for above table, the result should be:

```
Column1  | Column2  | Column3
-----------------------------
23.00%   | 27.60%   | 26.67%  
27.00%   | 24.48%   | 23.04%
25.00%   | 24.48%   | 24.90%
25.00%   | 23.44%   | 25.39%
```

This is the solution I used.
      dtTab.Columns.Add("TotalQty", GetType(Double))

```
    Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Object, Double)) = dtTab.Rows _
            .Cast(Of DataRow) _
            .GroupBy(Function(s As DataRow) s.Item("DateLabel")) _
            .SelectMany(Function(rows) rows.Select(Function(row) Tuple.Create(row.Item("Date"), Convert.ToDouble(rows.Sum(Function(dataRow) Convert.ToDouble(dataRow.Item("QTY")))))))

    For Each result As Tuple(Of Object, Double) In results
        Dim dRow As DataRow() = dtTab.Select(String.Format("Date ='{0}' ", result.Item1.ToString()))
        For Each row As DataRow In dRow
            row.SetField(Of System.Nullable(Of Double))("TotalQty", result.Item2)
        Next
    Next

    For Each row As DataRow In dtTab.Rows
        Dim total As Double = row.Item("TotalQty")
        total = Math.Round(total, 1)
        row.SetField(Of System.Nullable(Of Double))("QTY", Convert.ToDouble(row.Item("QTY")) / total * 100)
    Next

    dtTab.Columns.Remove("TotalQty")
    dtTab.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: Just put a % sign in front of them!

Comment: values can be big numbers and need to be converted into percentages , I just used simple ones to keep question simple..

Comment: The question is edited and its clear what the OP is asking now. Also it doesn't deserve such amount of downvotes now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add computed columns to your `DataTable` by setting [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property of  `DataColumn`.

Then you can format the data in your `DataGridView` using [`DefaultCellStyle.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the column.

For example suppose you have a `Table1` which contains `Column1`, then to add a computed column `Column1Percent` you can do this:

```
table1.Columns.Add("Column1Percent", double);
table1.Columns["Column1Percent"].Expression = "(Column1/SUM(Column1)) * 100";
this.DataGridView1.Columns["Column1Percent"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00'%'";
```

And then the result would be:

```
Column1 | Column1Percent
------------------------
1       | 20.00%
2       | 40.00%
2       | 40.00%
```

Comment: this is a good example but I cant add a new column. I need to update the existing Datatable or create a new Datatable.

Comment: You can add the column at run-time. You don't need to do that at design-time.

Comment: Thats what I did exactly.Thanks for your help.Not sure how I can mark your comment as answer?

Comment: You are welcome :) It's enough to click on check mark near the answer to mark it as accepted. :) [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) you can find more about accepting answers.